# How to click an href hyperlink using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hyperlink, click, href

I am writing a PowerShell script to login to a website and download some reports. I know next to nothing about PowerShell.

I've been able to frankenstein together a script that will login, but I am having trouble clicking the menu buttons. Inspect element shows the button (labeled "abc" in this case) as:

```
<a class="category-item-text" href="#">abc</a>
```

My current script looks like:

```
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

$username="MYUSERNAME"

$password="MYPASSWORD"

$ie.Navigate("https://MY.WEBPAGE/yada/yada/yada")

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('LOGIN_FIELD_LABEL')
$usernamefield.value = "$username"

$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('PASSWORD_FIELD_LABEL')
$passwordfield.value = "$password"

$Click=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button") | Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'submit'}
$Click.click()

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$ie.Navigate("https://MY.WEBPAGE/yada/yada/REPORTS")

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your power shell looks right, at least at first glance, but the HTML you show is for an anchor tag, not a button? Does it look like a normal HTML link when rendered? If so, your "Document.getElementsByTagName("button")" may need to be "Document.getElementsByTagName("a")?

Comment: @Mark I should have stated that I also know next to nothing about HTML/CSS/JS. Here is a screenshot of the code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AhGXjevXp-XhOke-Ewwd7RAYTw7o1DbT Thank you!!

Comment: @Mark When rendered there is a responsive sidebar menu where you can drill down into various navigation options. After navigating to the reports section, when clicking a sub-section for different types of reports, the non-menu portion of the page will buffer(?) momentarily and say loading, before displaying the selected reports. I'm not sure if this provides any insight. It looks like there is a JavaScript layer?

Comment: The button referenced in the above code is the login button, not the button I am trying to click now.

Comment: This worked for me (just needed the "a" tag hint from @Mark: $Click=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | Where-Object {$_.href -match 'abc'}
$Click.click()

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I needed to use getElementsByTagName("a"):

$Click=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | Where-Object {$_.href -match 'abc'}
$Click.click()